# Method not returning items within specified timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, interface, nopcommerce

Trying to figure out why this method isn't returning the items within the timespan I specified with some `DateTime` variables. I do get a result but it makes no sense and provide incorrect values.

The method is supposed to return all bestsellers from yesterday (the past 24 hours). However it seems that the method returns all bestsellers that have been sold since the beginning. In the Database there's a column called "CreatedOnUtc" wich provide a date, guess this could be used as a date to test but i don't know how to access it as it's in another class.

```
  public IList<BestsellersReportLine> DailyBestsellersReport()
        {
            int recordsToReturn = 5; int orderBy = 1; int groupBy = 1;
            var yesterDay = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
            var earliest = new DateTime(yesterDay.Year, yesterDay.Month, yesterDay.Day, 0, 0, 0);
            var latest = earliest.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, -1));
            var currentDay = DateTime.Now;
            var dayBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);


                var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                         where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore
                         join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                         join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                         join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                         select opv;


                var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
                    //group by product variants
                       from opv in query1
                       where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       :
                    //group by products
                       from opv in query1
                       where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       ;

                switch (orderBy)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
                }

                if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
                    query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

                var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
                {
                    var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
                    {
                        EntityId = x.EntityId,
                        TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                        TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
                    };
                    return reportLine;
                }).ToList();



                return result;

        }
```

There is a similar method wich has specified startTime and endTime, i believe it searches the database within a time record. Allthough this method is displayed in a view with choosable startDate/endDate in textboxes. However i need the time record for DailyBestsellersReport to be specified in the code as this will be a process running in the background.

Here is a similar period with DateTime parameteers:

```
public virtual IList<BestsellersReportLine> BestSellersReport(DateTime? startTime,
DateTime? endTime,int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1)
{
  some code...
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `where` clauses aren't actually testing any field from your database. You need to be testing the database fields, not some `c#` variables!

Comment: But the only thing i want to retrieve from the db is EntityId, TotalAmount and TotalQuantity from BestSellersReportLine. The DateTime Variables use to declare in what timespan to get the sold products from. In my case it's all the products sold yesterday. Are you saying i have to search the DB for wich products sold yesterday?

Comment: Yes, of course. Forget LINQ for a spell. If you'd do this is SQL, what would the `WHERE` clause look like?

Comment: I was suggested the WHERE clause was useful in this context. If i knew how it would look like i wouldn't be asking this question right? But it seem logical to search the db time record cuz that's where orders, sold products etc are recorded i guess..

Comment: `where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore` has nothing to do with db, so how can u expect it to filter rows in your database

Answer (score 1):

```
where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore
```

It's useless condition, it's allways true.
You need test for some 'time' fields from DB, if u want to filter your db records.

**Update** 
I suposed, that you have OrderDate column in _orderRepository.Table
than you snippet can be transformed into something like bellow:

```
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var today = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
var yesterDay = today.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

//suppose, that we gather all data for yesterday  
var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                 join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                 join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                 join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                 where yesterDay <= o.OrderDate && today >= o.OrderDate
                 select opv;

var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
    //group by product variants
       from opv in query1
       group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
       select new
       {
           EntityId = g.Key,
           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
       }
       :
    //group by products
       from opv in query1
       group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
       select new
       {
           EntityId = g.Key,
           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
       }
       ;
```

Comment: There's a method that pretty much do the same thing, except it is displayed in a view where the user have to choose a startdate or enddate in a textbox. This is a similar method and start/enddate seem to search the DB whithin a choosable time record. However i need the time record to be set in the code as this is a backgroundprocess that will be a sheduled task that runs once a day to display yesterdays bestsellers. -- public virtual IList<BestsellersReportLine> BestSellersReport(DateTime? startTime,
DateTime? endTime,int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1)
{some code...}